# Is it harmful to update columns which aren't changed?

Tags: postgresql, performance, update, query-performance

Say I have a table with some columns:

```
CREATE TABLE t
(
    key int PRIMARY KEY,
    c1  int,
    c2  text,
    c3  timestamptz
);
```

I now fetch a row from the table:

```
SELECT * FROM t WHERE id = 180;
```

In my application, I now only change the value of one column, let's say `c2`. Is it harmful performance-wise to do:

```
UPDATE t
SET    t1 = <exact the same value as before>,
       t2 = <new value>,
       t3 = <exact the same value as before>
WHERE  key = 180;
```

instead of:

```
UPDATE t
SET    t2 = <new value>
WHERE  key = 180;
```

?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming network overhead can be ignored (e.g. you're not updating megabytes of text with the same values), it should not affect performance.  However, if you have triggers for `UPDATE` with column lists, they will behave differently, depending on whether the column is mentioned as a target of `UPDATE`.  For instance,

```
create  trigger test_au after update of t1 on t
    for each row 
    execute procedure after_update_t1();

update t set t2=<new value> where key = 180; -- trigger does not fire
update t set t1=<exact the same value as before>,
 t2=<new value> where key = 180; -- trigger does fire
```

I also tested for HOT updates - no difference in Postgres 10.5. If the value of the indexed column doesn't change, it does a heap only update, at least according to `pg_stat_user_tables` - the same as if the indexed column doesn't participate in the update at all.